# How to access array indexes to do ordered prints with angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, key

From a json array, something like:

```
[{title: 'title1',
details: [{text: 'text1'},
    {code: 'code1'},
    {text: 'text2'},
    {code: 'code2'}, 
    {array: array1}]
...
},
{{title: 'title2',
details: [{text: 'text1'},
    {text: 'text2'},
    {array: array1},
    {code: 'code1'}, 
...
```

I would like to print datas of 3 different types: text, array and code.
Text any problem, array with

```
<table>
```

and code using [highlight module](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-highlightjs#installation) with

```
<pre><code highlight [code]="..."></code></pre>
```

Then, my first print should be:

```
text1
code1 in code style
text2
code2 in code style
array1 in array style
```

and the second:

```
text1
text2
array1 in array style
code1  in code style
```

I have some ideas to do this with *ngfor loop and ngif, but how to access on keys text, table and code to do ngif, please?
or if you see an easier solution?...

Comment: what have you tried so far ? and why was it not satisfactory?

Comment: It's a good order-keys problem, read again please ;)

Comment: Something like this... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgvhnc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashish Ranjan :) thanks to understand me (not as at least 3 people...) and thanks to help me. I will try to adapt your solution tomorrow but it seems fine. I notice your smart tip to use keys, nice!  :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have invalid array, on first element, it has duplicate key `code`. you  should use 1 key as `code` and then put object of all the codes on that index. however if that is just an example and you have a correct syntax of array and objects then use `*ngFor` to iterate on your array.

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of yourArray;" >

<p class="text">{{elem.text}}</p>

<pre><code highlight [code]={{elem.code}}></code></pre>

<!-- And it goes with all the elements you want to display. -->

</div>
```

Comment: No, it wasn't just an example. I did things like this because here order is important: text-code-texte-code-array then text-text-array-code.
I understand I have an invalid array but then how to do to respect good order?

Comment: your question is not understandable at all. First go and edit your question in clear and simple words. then provide enough information of what you want and what you tried, I tried my best to answer as per your question readability. Edit it and I'll edit my answer according to your question.